# Rails select query alias - how to tell if it's available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, alias

when using alias in a query, the alias is accessible  from the resulting objects

```
Model.select('field AS field_one').first.field_one
# => "value"
```

Given an instance of Model that can be the result of the above query or of another one, what's the best way to tell if that alias is available or not ? respond_to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best way to do that is to use read_attribute, which will return nil if the alias doesn't exist.

If you want to return something else than nil, you can do it with a method similar to:

```
def field_one
  read_attribute(:field_one) || 'some default value'
end
```